# Old PHP GD code no longer working

Tags: php, gd

I have a function which resizes images and whilst it works fine on my test server, it doesn#t work on the new live server. The error message i get is

Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open ' /home/sites/public_html/images/2013-24-1-240x300.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/sites/public_html/includes/functions/html_output.php on line 352

line 352 in the code below is the imagejpeg line near to the bottom.  If its creating the image on the fly, I dont understand why its trying to open the file.

Images folder is writeable (changed to 777 to check) as the original image is showing fine. GD is enabled on the live server bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

Both versions of PHP and GD are the same now on both servers. Only difference is test server is running WAMP and live is a linux.

```
function image_resample($src,$width,$height) {

    define(JPEGQUALITY, 75);
    define(ALLOWSQUASH,0.10);
    if ($src=='') {
            return $src;
     }
    $i = @getimagesize( $src );   // 1-gif (ignore), 2-jpeg, 3-png

    if (!(($width == SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH) && ($height == SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT)) && 
        !(($width == MEDIUM_IMAGE_WIDTH) && ($height == MEDIUM_IMAGE_HEIGHT))&&  
        !(($width == LARGE_IMAGE_WIDTH) && ($height == LARGE_IMAGE_HEIGHT)))  {
            return $src; // can amend to work with other images
     }
    if (!( ($i[2] == 3) || ($i[2] ==2))) {
            return $src;
     }

    $file = preg_replace( '/\.([a-z]{3,4})$/i', "-{$width}x{$height}.\\1", $src );   // name of resampled image
    if (is_file( $file ) ) {        
            return $file;
    }

    $scr_w         =  $i[0];
    $scr_h         = $i[1];
    if (($scr_w * $scr_h * $width * $height) == 0) {
            return $src;
     }

    $howsquashed = ($width / $height * $scr_h / $scr_w);
    if (((1 / (1 + ALLOWSQUASH)) < $howsquashed) && ($howsquashed < (1 + ALLOWSQUASH))) $simpleway='true';
    $scalefactor = min($width/$scr_w, $height/$scr_h);          
    $scaled_w        = (int)($scr_w * $scalefactor);
    $scaled_h         = (int)($scr_h * $scalefactor); 
    $offset_w        = max(0,round(($width - $scaled_w) / 2,0));
    $offset_h         = max(0,round(($height - $scaled_h) / 2)); 
     $dst = DIR_FS_CATALOG . '/' . $file; 
       $dstim = @imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height);
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate ($dstim, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefilledrectangle($dstim, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background_color);
    if ( $i[2] == 2) {
            $srcim = @ImageCreateFromJPEG ($src); // open
    }
    elseif ( $i[2] == 3) {
            $srcim         = @ImageCreateFromPNG ($src);
    }
    if ($simpleway == 'true') {        
            imagecopyresampled ($dstim, $srcim, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $scr_w, $scr_h);        
    }
    else {
            $intim = @imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height); 
            imagecopyresampled ($intim, $srcim, $offset_w, $offset_h, 0, 0, $scaled_w, $scaled_h, $scr_w, $scr_h);
            imagecopy ( $dstim, $intim, $offset_w, $offset_h, $offset_w, $offset_h, $scaled_w, $scaled_h);
            imagedestroy ($intim);
    }
    if ( $i[2] == 2) {
            imagejpeg ($dstim , $dst , JPEGQUALITY);  
    }
    elseif ( $i[2] == 3) {
            imagepng ($dstim , $dst);
    }
    imagedestroy ($srcim);
    imagedestroy ($dstim);
    return $file;                 // Use the newly resampled image
}
```

Comment: What's the error? And have you verified GD is in fact enabled on your production server?

Comment: Take off those [`@`](http://php.net/@)'s for starters.

Comment: And do not define constant inside functions. You will get notices on multiple function calls.

Comment: @Skidoosh I have updated the question to show that no images are generated and that GD is enabled.

Comment: What's the version of GD in your development environment?

Comment: hmm its the same version :-( Maybe its not a GD issue!

Comment: "it doesn't work on the new live server." Please say i) What you expected. ii) What you're actually seeing.

Comment: Some extra digging has turned up that the imagejpeg function cant write the file, even though the folder has 777 permissions.
Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open ' /home/sites/public_html/images/2013-24-1-240x300.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/sites/public_html/includes/functions/html_output.php on line 352 error

but thats correct because the file shouldnt exist yet as the function is trying to create it.

Answer (score 1):

the message is pretty clear

```
Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open ' /home/sites/public_html/images/2013-24-1-240x300.jpg'
 for writing: No such file or directory in 
/home/sites/public_html/includes/functions/html_output.php on line 352
```

if the directory exists chmod it so the apache user can write to it.

if the directory doesnt exist create it and then chmod it (644 should be enough)

if the file exists already - it can not over write it, So chmod the file (its likely you used SCP to transfer it and its under the user you SCP'ed as) `ls -l` to confirm the permissions

Comment: The directory exists and has been chmod to 777. However im not sure who has permissions on it as filezilla is just showing as 885460 885134 for owner/group. I need to talk to the host and see why I user cant write to its own folders I think.

Comment: make a php file and <pre>echo exec("ls -l /home/sites/public_html/images/");

Comment: Its giving me the following
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username      52 Nov 18  2012 triangle_up.gif

Comment: have you put username in there ? does echo exec("whoami"); show the same name ?

Comment: Yes sorry I replaced the username with 'username' and it shows the same as the output from whoami.

Comment: try ls -l /home/sites/public_html/.

Comment: ok I got -rw-r--r--  1 username username   942 Mar  8 10:00 whatsnew.php

Comment: the folder doesnt exist according to that output

Comment: can you explain exactly what that exec command should do please.

Comment: it should list all of the files and folders with extended permissions. If its listing one file, Then theres only 1 file in the dir you shown.

Comment: Thats odd because the images folder contains over 500 images and the public html folder contains a whole website which im browsing now, so I know the files are there. hmm I need to investigate :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31972/discussion-between-user1281385-and-paul-m)